# python3 struct.pack with strings as parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, struct.pack

i'm actually wondering about python3's struct.pack behaviour, but maybe i missed something.

i'm submitting an .jpg file via UDP. Btw: the `socket.sendTo()` and `sendAll()` function throws a "Python IOError: [Errno 90] Message too long" when i try to submit the whole file (~200kB) at once. So i submit the file in pieces of 1024 bytes. No prob, i'm just wondering why i find *nothing* about this size-limitation in the python docs.

Anyway, my main issue is: i need struct.pack to put some information at the beginning of each piece -> 2 fixed-size strings.

but when i do

```
chunk = struct.pack("!3c4cI", bytes("JPG", "utf-8"), bytes(dev_id, "utf-8"), i)
```

it goes "struct.error: pack expected 8 items for packing (got 3)"

so i have to go

```
chunk = struct.pack("!3c4ci", b"J", b"P", b"G", 
    bytes(dev_id[0:1], "utf-8"),
    bytes(dev_id[1:2], "utf-8"),
    bytes(dev_id[2:3], "utf-8"),
    bytes(dev_id[3:4], "utf-8"), i)
```

to make it work. Why is that!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct.pack` requires that each item is passed as a separate argument. Additionally  Python makes distinction between `char` and `byte`, even though in C they're synonyms, that's why you need to have one-byte `bytes` values for the `c`, instead of integers in range 0 .. 255.

However, `struct` also supports the `s` format specifier, where `s` stands for a string of given length:

```
>>> dev_id, i = 'R2D2', 42
>>> struct.pack("!3s4sI", b"JPG", dev_id.encode(), i)
b'JPGR2D2\x00\x00\x00*'
```

---

Alternatively, if you're using at least Python **3.5**, then thanks to [PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) you can use the `B` (unsigned byte) format in conjunction with splat operator `*` like this:

```
>>> struct.pack("!3B4BI", *b"JPG", *dev_id.encode(), i)
```

What `*` does here is to unpack every byte from the given `bytes` value as an integer within range 0 ... 255 into separate arguments; if `dev_id.encode()` results in 4 UTF-8 bytes, then a total of 8 arguments will be passed to the `struct.pack`. And unlike `c`, `B` accepts a single byte value as an integer.

---

P.S. notice that I used `b'JPG'` directly instead of calling `bytes('JPG', 'UTF-8')`, and likewise called `.encode()` on the string which encodes in `UTF-8` by default, for shorter code.